# Getting asset serial number via lookup

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, lookup, form

I have created a custom object named `AssetLookup` which has a lookup to an `Asset` record.

I added it to my controller:

```
public class LicenseActivationController {
    public Asset_Lookup__c assetLookup { get; set; }

    public void activateLicense() {
        // assetLookup.Asset__r is null here, despite me selecting an asset using the lookup control.
        // I need to get the serial number of the asset here: assetLookup.Asset__r.SerialNumber
    }
}
```

I wrapped it inside a form in my VisualForce page:

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:inputField value="{!assetLookup.Asset__c}" id="assetLookup" />
    <apex:commandButton value="Activate" action="{!ActivateLicense}" />
</apex:form>
```

But, the problem is that it seems to be null on post. Why is it null and what can I do to get the record back on a from post? Specifically I tried getting the serial number using `assetLookup.Asset__r.SerialNumber` but it tries to de-reference a null object, despite me selecting an asset using the lookup relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the concept of a lookup field.

What a lookup field essentially is, is an ID field. So, when you're selecting the 'Asset' record with the lookup field, you're setting the 'Asset_Lookup__c' records 'Asset__c' ID to be equal to the selected assets ID.

So, you have to query the asset record.

```
public void activateLicense() {
    // Essential NULL check
    if(assetLookup == null || assetLookup.Asset__c == null) {
        // NULL Values, error message maybe?
        return;
    }
    // Here you need a query
    Asset selected = [SELECT SerialNumber FROM Asset WHERE Id = :assetLookup.Asset__c];

    // You can now access the 'SerialNumber' field of the asset record
    String serial = selected.SerialNumber;
}
```

Also, in the constructor, you have to initialize the "assetLookup" variable:

```
public LicenseActivationController() {
    assetLookup = new Asset_Lookup__c();
}
```